# What is the difference between "next" and "after" entries in LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

What is the difference between the fields `next` and `after` in the `LinkedHashMap$Entry` class ? It does not always yield the same result, sometimes they hold the same object, sometimes not. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next` belongs to the `HashMap.Node` base class. It holds a reference to the next entry in the current bin of the `HashMap`.

`after` is a property of `LinkedHashMap.Entry`, which holds a reference to the next entry according to iteration order (which by default is insertion order).

There is no reason for the two to hold the same reference (unless the insertion order corresponds with the order in which the entries are stored in the bins, and even then, the last entry in each bin will always have `next == null`, while it can have a not null `after`).

Comment: So what would be the use case if it effectively is the same reference ?

Comment: @YassineBadache It is not the same reference. `next` is used when you search for a key/add a key/remove a key. `after` is used when you iterate over the keys/entries/values.

Comment: Yeah, I get it, I mean, the use case when `next` and `after` are referencing the same object. It happens to me on my current job, I am trying to find an answer on this bug: the size of the `Map` is , but the effective table only holds 2 elements. Thank you for the enlightment on the subject.

Comment: @YassineBadache If they are referencing the same object, it's a coincidence, but not a bug.